# Spring ServletContext returns null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Stuck with the strange prob. I'm adding a ServletContext to my class (defined as @Service) and it  always returns null. Tried both @Autowired and without it.

Also i didn't receive any error on app startup.
Only the null value when i call 'servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/")'

This is a class where i'm trying to use it:

```
@Service
public class MyFactory  implements ServletContextAware {

    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }

    private someMethod(){
       servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/"); //this return null
    }

}
```

P.S `servletContext` itself is null, not a `.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/")` method

Comment: You are of course letting Spring instantiate the class for you, not calling `new MyFactory()` yourself, right? And `someMethod()` is called *after* autowiring completes too, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem description is confusing. You say you add `ServletContext` and *it* returns null (`@Autowired` or not), making it sound like the value of `servletContext` is null, when your wording and code example otherwise seems to indicate that `getRealPath()` is returning null.

If `servletContext` is null, then `servletContext.getRealPath()` will cause a `NullPointerException`.

If `servletContext` is not null, then `servletContext.getRealPath()` will succeed, but *may* return null.

Quoting javadoc of [`getRealPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29):

> This method returns `null` if the servlet container is unable to translate the given *virtual* path to a *real* path.

So, if `/WEB-INF/` is in a .war file that hasn't been unpacked, there is no real path, and `getRealPath()` will return null.

Comment: Sorry, you right, the problem's description is not clear enough.

servletContext is null.